# Using 'extendData' in a 'dcc.Interval' event will only update my graph when I'm browsing another Chrome tab

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I created a very simple (one page) application in Dash that appends random data to a plotly chart using a `dcc.Interval` component and the `extendData` method (I'd like to have x values max).
The program worked like a charm, until I tried to port it to a multi-page application:

I used the following example:

https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/blob/main/examples/python/templates/multi-page-apps/responsive-collapsible-sidebar/sidebar.py
and replaced:

```py
elif pathname == "/page-1":
        return html.P("This is the content of page 1. Yay!")
```

with:

```py
import page_1

...

elif pathname == "/page-1":
        return page_1.layout
```

My page_1.py contains the following code:

```py
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objs as go


layout = dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([
        html.H4('Live Feed'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph',
                    figure=go.Figure({'data': 
                        [
                            {'x': [], 'y': []},
                            {'x': [], 'y': []},
                            {'x': [], 'y': []},
                            {'x': [], 'y': []}
                        ] 
                    }),
                    ),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=0.1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ]
))
```

I put my Callback in my app.py file:

```py
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'extendData'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
              )
def update_graph_live(n):
    # Collect some data
    y1 = np.random.normal(loc = 10, scale=10)
    y2 = y1 + random.randint(-5, 5)
    y3 = y2 + random.randint(-10, 60)
    y4 = y3 + random.randint(-40, 2)
    return [{'x': [[datetime.datetime.now()]] * 4,'y': [[y1], [y2], [y3], [y4]]}, [0,1, 2, 3], 300]

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Unfortunatly, my chart will only update when I'm browsing another tab in Chrome, not when I'm displaying it.

I have another page with some other components and an associated callback declared in my app.py file as :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("result-code", "children"),
    Input("slider", "value"),
)
def create_python_script(slider):
    
    
    markdown = markdown_start
        
    markdown += '''
    msg = {{
        "slider_value": {slider}  
    }}'''.format(slider=slider)

    markdown += markdown_end
    
    return markdown
```

And my Markdown component is updated in real-time, no problem with that.

Here is a copy of my callback status:

[Callback status in Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOtoY.png)

My developper console shows every incoming message in the front-end part:

```
{
  "multi": true,
  "response": {
    "live-update-graph": {
      "extendData": [
        {
          "x": [
[
              "2023-02-13T16:58:37.533426"
            ],
[
              "2023-02-13T16:58:37.533426"
            ],
[
              "2023-02-13T16:58:37.533426"
            ],
[
              "2023-02-13T16:58:37.533426"
            ]
          ],
          "y": [
[
              -4.26648933108117
            ],
[
              -3.2664893310811696
            ],
[
              -8.26648933108117
            ],
[
              -9.26648933108117
            ]
          ]
        },
[
0,
1,
2,
3
        ],
300
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using http://localhost:8888 instead of http://127.0.0.1:8888 to connect to my web app and somehow didn't see it, and that was preventing the chart from being updated.